# How to analyze the thread-safety of an existing code?

Tags: c#, dependencies, thread-safety

**Context:** I have a code base in C# to maintain, which uses several dependencies.

**Question:** How can I approach the problem of **analyzing whether the code is thread-safe?**. Do I need to read/analyze the source code of the dependencies? Or just assume that they are thread-safe (when the documentation doesn't say anything)?

Please note that my question is not **how to write thread-safe code in the first place?** as there are known best practices for this you can adhere to when writing the new code line by line.

I know that I can read/analyze my own code to see if it follows the best practices for thread-safety. Or I can use static analysis tools to do some (limited) analysis and fix the reported issues. But regarding the dependencies, how far I need to go for analysis?

Comment: "Or just assume that they are thread-safe (when the documentation doesn't say anything)?" -- the default assumption should be that code is NOT thread safe.  Many libraries are not, most old code is not.  Code and libraries might contain global state for resources, or only support single-threaded access to data structures and/or resources.

Comment: Thank you @DaveS for the response.
So you mean the idea of reviewing dependency's source code is reasonable. Yes?

Comment: If you can find something saying that X is safe and its use of libraries Y, Z is done safely, then you can decide to trust that.  If you have no documentation saying it's safe, then you need to look at how X uses Y,Z yourself.  For example, file I/O functions are often not thread safe but the use of them in a logging library might be safe if it uses a single worker thread for all log writes to files.  (multiple thread-safe producers of log entries into a circular buffer, one consumer thread that does all file I/O).